# How to make a div in XML read as html?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to embed content generated by an external API into a web page. I've got the output styled as I want it, except I want to have one of the XML `div`s read as HTML to create a live link. Right now, the output just shows the raw code with the `a` and such rather than just making the anchor into an anchor. Is there a CSS element I can use to tell the browser to a `div` as HTML? If not CSS, is there anything else I can do?

```
<style type="text/css">
.csl-entry {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
 }
.csl-block {
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 4em;
 }
  </style>

<p>
<font style="line-height:200%">
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div class="csl-bib-body" style="line-height: 1.35; padding-left: 2em; text-indent:-2em;">
  <div class="csl-entry">Attridge, Derek, ed. <i>James Joyce&#x2019;s Ulysses: A Casebook</i>. Oxford University Press, USA, 2004.</div>
  <div class="csl-entry">Gifford, Don, and Robert J. Seidman. <i>Ulysses Annotated: Notes for James Joyce&#x2019;s Ulysses</i>. 2 Rev Enl. University of California Press, 2008.</div>
  <div class="csl-entry">Gilbert, Stuart. <i>James Joyce&#x2019;s Ulysses: A Study</i>. 2nd ed. Vintage, 1987. &lt;a href=&#x201C;test&#x201D;&gt;TEST URL with HTML&lt;/a&gt;

    <div class="csl-block">&lt;a href=&#x201C;test&#x201D;&gt;TEST EXTRA WITH LINK&lt;/a&gt;.</div>
</div>
  <div class="csl-entry">Joyce, James. <i>Ulysses (Gabler Edition) 1st (first) Edition Text Only</i>, 1986.</div>
  <div class="csl-entry">Kenner, Hugh. <i>Ulysses</i>. Revised. The Johns Hopkins University Press, 1987.</div>
</div>
</font>
</p>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are working with

Comment: I'm trying, but I'm new to this and can't figure out how to display the code without having some of it execute, but here's a short test file that illustrates it; view-source:http://www.math.grinnell.edu/~simpsone/zotero.php. There's a div class called "csl-block" in the XML. I've put the "a href" code in that field to create a link, but the browser reads it as plain text. Is there a way to tell the browser to read the "csl-block" chunks as HTML instead of displaying them as-is? I hope this helps.

Comment: You can wrap small blocks of text in `, and you can wrap large blocks of text by entering 2 new lines and using 4 spaces. I will try to edit your code so that you see what I mean

Comment: Thanks, Cody. I don't follow you yet, so any example you could provide would be very useful.

Comment: Put your code in the question and I will edit it so that it shows up

Comment: Oh, gotcha, sorry. Done.